# Объясните, пожалуйста, решение задачи

Tags: python, python-3.x

Наткнулся на такое вот решение задачи:

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    return [ch for i, ch in enumerate(iterable) if i == 0 or ch != iterable[i - 1]]

iterable = 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'
print(unique_in_order(iterable))
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что написано в `return`?  Я понимаю, что это какой-то генератор списка, но весь этот синтаксис мне не понятен совсем... Пытался разобрать её по ходам в дебагере пайчарма, но он сразу выводит ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно переписать так, чтобы было понятнее:

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    l = []                                  # пустой список
    for i, ch in enumerate(iterable):       # для каждого элемента ch с индексом i в последовательности iterable
        if i == 0 or ch != iterable[i - 1]: # если индекс равен нулю либо элемент не равен предыдущему элементу
            l.append(ch)                    # добавляем элемент в список
    return l                                # возвращаем получившийся список

iterable = 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'
print(unique_in_order(iterable))
```

Answer (score 0):

`ch for i, ch in enumerate(iterable)` - вернуть каждый элемент списка `iterable`

`if i == 0 or ch != iterable[i-1]` - если элемент первый или он не равен предыдущему