# Что значит [obj for object, ...]?

Tags: python

```
from collections import Counter

def frequency_sort(items):
    # your code here
    result = [obj for objects, c in Counter(items).most_common() for obj in [objects] * c]
    return result
```

Объясните работу result, а конкретно [obj for object, что значит данное выражение.

Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1160784/398802

Answer (score 2, accepted):

эта конструкция называется `list comprehension`

ваша конструкция `result = [obj for objects, c in Counter(items).most_common() for obj in [objects] * c]`
аналогична следующей по семантике:

```
from collections import Counter

result = []
for objects, c in Counter(items).most_common():
    for obj in [objects] * c:
        result.append(obj)
```

следует иметь ввиду, что списковые включения в большинстве случаев работают гораздо быстрее самописных циклов из-за внутренних оптимизаций

Comment: Можно ссылку, подтверждающую это "списковые включения работают гораздо быстрее самописных циклов, **так как они напрямую вызывают код на Си**"?

Comment: @dIm0n что списковые включения более оптимизированы думаю вы точно знаете, а про код на Си это у Лутца прочитал, что списковые включения сразу вызывают код на Си, а самописные циклы долго интерпретируются вначале

Comment: @dIm0n https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list нашел на стаке хорошее пояснение и я был не совсем прав, поэтому поправлю немного

Comment: Я нашёл в том же вопросе комментарий, опровергающий эти слова :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list#comment89180601_30245627

Comment: @dIm0n да там неоднозначно в общем))

Comment: @ildar , а можешь объяснить подробнее выражение obj for object, только это в принципе не понятно было

Comment: @Alealan раскрыл же подробно в ответе как выглядит это выражение если переписать его в виде обычных циклов...

Comment: @Alealan, не `obj for object`, а `obj for obj in seq`: `in` неотделимо от `for`. Это значит что из набора объектов `seq` (то что справа от `in`) берется объект `obj` (то что между `for` и `in`), и над этим объектом выполняется какая-то операция (слева от `for`). В примере из вопроса из набора берутся объекты попарно, поэтому они разделяются запятой (разделяются два объекта - `objects` и `c`).

Comment: Господи, открыли глаза мне, спасибо вам))